# What is wrong with my code? Getting Compile error Next without: For

Tags: vba

Trying to link color from one worksheet to another based on value of cell.

```
Sub ColorMeAug()

Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For i = 10 To 45

      Set r1 = Range("Aug!D" & i & ":Aug!M" & i)
      Set r2 = Range("Year!x" & i & ":Year!S" & i)
      If r1.Value = 1 Then
        r2.Interior.Color = vbWhite
      If r1.Value = 2 Then
        r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      If r1.Value = 3 Then
        r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I am VERY new to this.  Trying to link color from one worksheet to another based on value of cell.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe in detail what it is you need to do, how you are trying to do it, and where you are stuck. In this case, we would want to know what line the error occurs on.

Comment: Programmning questions are usually better placed on our sister-site StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry Tonny. I thought I had signed up for that site.  I have a full year calendar for worksheet one and the next 12 worksheets are full months.  I am trying have the color of the date cell in both month and year worksheets update according to a number indicated in an adjoining cell.  I have a module for one instance working but need it to work for the entire workbook.  I will post that module next.

Comment: Sub ColorMeElmo()
Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For i = 2 To 5
      Set r1 = Range("Aug!D34")
      Set r2 = Range("Year!S17")
      If r1.Value = 1 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbWhite
      If r1.Value = 2 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      If r1.Value = 3 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
   Next i
End Sub

Comment: Why not localize each month in the yearsheet with the array of numbers, then do a lookup to modify year cell colour. That should be easy to fill

Comment: Spreadsheet programming is an essential skill for EE’s but best answered in Superuser

Comment: Thank you Tony.  I will try that.

Comment: @SonyaMorse - Please do not use commentary to clarify your question.  Instead you should edit your question.  Your comment is not properly formatted and the code cannot be easily read since it's not formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

Your first 2 "if" statements don't have a matching "end if".
(End if is NOT optional in VBA.)

Fix that first. Then see what happens.

Comment: This is it. I might use `Select Case` instead as it works more like the user is trying to do.

Comment: `If`, then replace the remaining `If`s with `Elseif` until the `End If`

Comment: Now I get Run-time error 13 MisMatch

Comment: @SonyaMorse - **We do not debug code through commentary.**

Answer (score 0):

As indicated above, you are missing some correct closures for some of your if statements.

However, it may be considered that using If or Case statements is an inappropriate coding solution in this case.  Instead you should be considering using a Dictionary based solution.  The reason for considering a Dictionary based solution is that there is a fixed 1:1 relationship between your cell values and the colour you want to apply.

Rewriting your code to use a dictionary gives (as a first attempt)

```
Option Explicit

Private InteriorColours As Scripting.Dictionary


Sub ColorMeAug()

    If InteriorColours Is Nothing Then SetupInteriorColours
     
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 10 To 45

        Dim r1 As Range
        Set r1 = Range("Aug!D" & i & ":Aug!M" & i)
    
        If InteriorColours.Exists(r1.Value) Then
          
            Range("Year!x" & i & ":Year!S" & i).Interior.Color = InteriorColours.Item(r1.Value)
          
        Else
          
            'raise error for no such colour
            
        End If
    
    Next i
    
End Sub


Public Sub SetupInteriorColours()

    Set InteriorColours = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    With InteriorColours
    
        .Add 1, vbWhite
        .Add 2, vbYellow
        .Add 3, vbRed
        'etc
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to have added a reference to the Microsoft Scripting runtime.